# PHP: Pushing form input values to another page via Submit in a session

Tags: php

I have a PHP page with a session set up that will post a Session ID, a randomly generated identifier and a name variable (via input form) to a validation / processing page to store them in a database. The first two are simple enough as session_id remains the same between the two pages.

However, the name from the form is giving me trouble. How do I set a Submit button properly in this case? When I use POST like this...

```
<FORM action="setup.php">

<INPUT type="text" name="user_name" maxlength="20"> 

<INPUT type="text" name="user_address">

<INPUT Type="submit" value="Accept" method="post">

</FORM>
```

And then try to retrieve the values in setup.php via ...

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

$user_address = $_POST['user_address'];
```

... after initializing the session again, it returns an "Undefined index: user_name" in setup.php. How do I get these input values to port properly?

Comment: +1 Scuzzy, so your form tag should look like  `<FORM action="setup.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<FORM action="setup.php">
```

to

```
<FORM action="setup.php" method="post">
```

Otherwise it's going to assume a GET request and will not create the `$_POST` global variable

Comment: Well don't I feel silly now.